# POST con URLSearchParams(); No Funciona

Tags: angularjs-2.0, ionic, ionic2

Hola intento hacer un post para un login y no me envia los datos, este es el codigo.. IONIC

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { URL_SERVICES } from '../../config/url.services';

import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class UsersProvider {

  token:string;
  id_user:string;

  constructor(public http: Http,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    console.log('Hello UsersProvider Provider');
  }

  ingresar( email:string, password:string){
    console.log("usersP ",email);
    console.log("usersP ", password);

    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append("email", email);
    data.append("password", password);

    let url = URL_SERVICES + "login";

    return this.http.post( url, data )
                    .map( resp => {

                      let data_resp = resp.json();
                      console.log( data_resp );

                      if( data_resp.err ){
                        this.alertCtrl.create({
                          title: 'Error al iniciar',
                          subTitle: data_resp.message,
                          buttons: ['OK']
                        }).present();

                      }else{
                        this.token = data_resp.token;
                        this.id_user = data_resp.id_user;

                        //GUARDAR STORAGE
                      }

                    });

  }

}
```

el archivo de url.config

```
export const URL_SERVICES = "http://localhost/appWC/index.php/";
```

el login.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { URL_SERVICES } from '../../config/url.services';

import { AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Injectable()
export class UsersProvider {

  token:string;
  id_user:string;

  constructor(public http: Http,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController) {
    console.log('Hello UsersProvider Provider');
  }

  ingresar( email:string, password:string){
    console.log("usersP ",email);
    console.log("usersP ", password);

    let data = new URLSearchParams();
    data.append("email", email);
    data.append("password", password);

    let url = URL_SERVICES + "login";

    return this.http.post( url, data )
                    .map( resp => {

                      let data_resp = resp.json();
                      console.log( data_resp );

                      if( data_resp.err ){
                        this.alertCtrl.create({
                          title: 'Error al iniciar',
                          subTitle: data_resp.message,
                          buttons: ['OK']
                        }).present();

                      }else{
                        this.token = data_resp.token;
                        this.id_user = data_resp.id_user;

                        //GUARDAR STORAGE
                      }

                    });

  }

}
```

el login.html

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label fixed>Correo </ion-label>
  <ion-input type="email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
</ion-item>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label fixed>Contraseña </ion-label>
  <ion-input type="password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: te falta importa la libreria ! `import {URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';` dime si funciono para agregar la respuesta

Comment: si, eso era!!!!!!, Gracias.. uff después de 3 horas de tirarle cabeza..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando un modulo en Angular sin importarlo!
, debes importar el modulo

```
 import {URLSearchParams} from '@angular/http';
```

mas acerca del modulo puedes ver la [documentacion](https://angular.io/api/http/URLSearchParams)

**Adicional**

Como ya tienes cargado un modulo de `@angular/http` puedes hacer

```
import { Http , URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

asi tu codigo queda mejor esteticamente